# Sending normalized vertex attribute produces garbage

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to send a color attribute to my GLSL shader.

The colors are stored in a tightly packed byte array with 3 consecutive bytes making up an RGB triplet.
The shader expects a `vec3` so I call `glVertexAttribPointer` to send normalized float values to the shader.

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, attributeBuffers[COLOR]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.n_vertices() * 3 * sizeof(GLubyte), color, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// a little later
glEnableVertexAttribArray(attributes[COLOR]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, attributeBuffers[COLOR]);
glVertexAttribPointer(attributes[COLOR], 3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, 0, 0);
```

What happens is that:

1. The colors don't seem to arrive in the shader, the vertices are colored in a single green color
2. The application takes a massive performance hit

When I manually normalize the color values, copy them to a float array and send that to OpenGL it renders without any problem:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, attributeBuffers[COLOR]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.n_vertices() * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), colorf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// a little later
glEnableVertexAttribArray(attributes[COLOR]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, attributeBuffers[COLOR]);
glVertexAttribPointer(attributes[COLOR], 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

I tested this on an AMD graphics card with an OpenGL 3.0 context.

Why is this happening? Am I missing something?

Comment: It sounds like a bug, but then again, 3 bytes per vertex is GPU unfriendly. Try to pass 4 bytes instead, padding the 4th.

Comment: The shader actually expects a `vec4`, you just happen to be defining only 3 of the 4-components. That is fine, but do not expect stellar performance because this leads to misaligned memory access. There are 3-component formats that are a power-of-two that you can use for vertex colors, like `UNSIGNED_INT_10F_11F_11F_REV`. Granted that is an FP format, but you get the idea -- 3-component data types work best when packed to a power-of-two (even when that means an uneven distribution of precision). *Adding an extra 1-byte to your stride can accomplish the same task.*

Comment: What you're trying should work, as far as I can tell. I was looking for alignment restrictions in the specs, and came up mostly empty. The closest I found was "Clients must align data elements consistent with the requirements of the client platform" under `BufferData()`, but I don't think that should be a problem in this case. I would certainly try what the comments above suggested, and use 4 components. Generally, it's not unusual to get poor performance with rarely used data types and alignments. Some hardware might not directly support them, and the driver support is not exercised much.

Comment: Indeed, I did not mean to imply that this is in any way invalid, I just wanted to explain the "massive performance hit." GL implementations are required to support odd-ball memory alignment for vertex attributes, the same way they support 8-bit vertex indices even though the hardware cannot use them efficiently. The API allows you to do things that are not hardware friendly, and short of using Debug Output you may never realize the problem. Speaking of which, since this is an AMD driver, it probably spits out a performance warning to debug output -- AMD is very detailed in its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As per Bahbar's suggestion I am now aligning the color triplets to 32-bits and it works flawlessly. Colors arrive correctly in the shader and there is no performance hit at all.

Comment: Leaving the question open because this fixes my issue at hand but I'd still be interested in why exactly this is happening